# Scholastic anthology book with a yellow cover; includes a story where a town gets together and sings, creating some sort of magic

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, urban-fantasy, scholastic

If this helps, I went to school in the Dominican Republic during the 1990s. As part of our school supplies for 6th-8th grade, we had to purchase a collection of Scholastic books containing short stories.  The cover was plain yellow, and it contained perhaps a few black and white illustrations for each story.

The particular book I am looking ends with a town that gets together and sings, literally ends with everyone singing, and the moment is really powerful. The singing ends up creating some sort of magic, or protecting the town they are in. The magic has some sort of butterfly shapes?

There was also another story about a kid who is visiting his dad and he is just describing the way to the house, the busy street, his lunch, etc. I am almost 40, meaning I have been looking for almost 20 years…

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: A plain yellow cover sounds more like a Gollancz publication. I remember when I was a child Gollancz used to publish books with a plain yellow cover with the title in black lettering.

Comment: For example [the Spectrum anthologies](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31594).

Comment: Gollancz? Will investigate, but I am almost 98% certain it was scholastic. The logo is very simple and recognizable. The illustrations  are similar to Harry Potter…

Comment: Here's a list of [Scholastic anthologies](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=pub_publisher&O_1=contains&TERM_1=Scholastic&C=AND&USE_2=pub_ctype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=ANTHOLOGY) sorted by publication date.

Comment: That first one really sounds like "The Grinch Who Stole Christmas".

Answer (score 3):

A long shot: Centerburg Tales/ Robert McCloskey, is the right reading level, has BW drawings and there is a story called  "Pie and Punch and You-Know-Whats" where the whole town is infected by a catchy jukebox tune and Homer Price (the MC of most of the stories) finds a "counter spell" ditty to counter act it. There are no butterflies, but the last drawing has a pile of books, one or two are overturned. Maybe mistaken as butterflies from the distance of 20 years?
I found most of the story on google books:
[Centerburg Tales](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=brSKBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Sorry. I checked this out and it’s not the correct one. The book felt more like magical realism and less about Americana… it’s was simply written, like the little prince.

Comment: As I said, It was a long shot. Good luck.